# How do I manually install Cloudera with Parcels without an internet connection?

Tags: hadoop, redhat, cloudera

I'm trying to install Cloudera 5.7 on RedHat 6.  In the Cloudera Manager Wizard GUI, on the "Select Repository" screen, I check "User Parcels (Recommended)."  But I see no option for "Select the version of CDH."  I have no internet connection.  I do not want to use packages.  What should I do to install Parcels?  I cannot continue the installation using Parcels.

Answer (score 1):

You will find instruction here for 5.7: 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cm_ig_create_local_parcel_repo.html

For latest version of CDH:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_create_local_parcel_repo.html